# ContentRootPath different in Development and Azure web app

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

When I deploy my Dot Net Core web app to Azure, the `Environment.ContentRootPath` variable is set to `[myproject]/wwwroot`.  However, in development, it is just `[myproject]`.

Why does it change in Azure deployment?

How can I make it consistent?

For reference, this is my `IWebHost`.

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                {
                    var env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;

                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true);

                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                        config.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();

                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
                .UseApplicationInsights()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
                .Build();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/), you could find that your web contents are deployed to `D:\home\site\wwwroot` as follows:

[image]

By default, `D:\home\site\wwwroot` would be used as the content root and the host would search the content files (e.g. MVC view files,etc.) when hosting your application on Azure Web App.

In development, your app is started from the project's root folder, so the project's root folder is used as the content root.

Per my understanding, you may misunderstand the `wwwroot` folder in your project with the `wwwroot` folder on Azure Web App for storing your web content.

Moreover, you could use `UseContentRoot` to customize your content root folder. If the path doesn't exist, the host would fail to start. Details you could follow [Hosting in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x).