# IWebHostEnvironment ContentRootPath in Azure App Service not the same as local

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0

I've an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project. I'm reading some data from local Data folder (in root of project) (outside wwwroot folder!). When running local, I can get this path with ' IWebHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath'. However, when uploading the project to Azure App Service, ContentRootPath is located in public wwwroot folder. How can I access the Data folder when hosted in Azure App Service?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117825/unable-to-load-static-file-once-it-has-been-published-to-azure-using-asp-net-co

Answer (score 2):

According to my test, the content root path in Azure Web app is `D:\home\site\wwwroot` and the webroot path in Azure web app is `D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot`. So you may misunderstand the `wwwroot` folder in your project with the `wwwroot` folder on Azure Web App for storing your web content.

My `HomeController`

```
 private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _env = env;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            string contentRootPath = _env.ContentRootPath;
            string webRootPath = _env.WebRootPath;

            return Content("Content Root Path: "+contentRootPath + "\nWeb Root Path: " + webRootPath);
        }
```

My website url: https://webv3.azurewebsites.net
[image]

Regarding that, we also can check it via [Kudo](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu)
[image]
[image]
[image]

For more details, please refer to [ContentRootPath different in Development and Azure web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48261249/contentrootpath-different-in-development-and-azure-web-app)

Comment: I wish you showed your Startup.cs as well